# Changing spelling for multiple words at a time in R/replacing many words at once

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataset (survey) and a column of birth_country, where people have written their country of birth. An example of it:

```
    1 america
    2 usa
    3 american
    4 us of a
    5 united states
    6 england
    7 english
    8 great britain
    9 uk 
    10 united kingdom
```

how I would like it to look:

```
1 america
2 america
3 america
4 america
5 america
6 uk
7 uk
8 uk
9 uk
10 uk
```

I have tried using str_replace to manually insert the different spellings, to replace them with 'america' but when I look at my dataset, nothing has changed
e.g.

```
survey <- structure(list(birth_country = c("america", "usa", "american", "us of a", "united states", "england", "english", "great britain",  "uk", "united kingdom")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

survey$birth_country <- str_replace(survey$birth_country, ' "united state"|"united statea"|"united states of america"', "america")
```

thank you in advance

Comment: It will still require some effort, but you can use regex for more flexible matching. Here's a good [R regex cheat sheet](https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf). For example, to match 'america' and 'american', you can use a regex like `^american?$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in how you specified your regular expression. Try this (updated based on @Gabriella 's comment, and another tidyverse approach, similar to @MarBIo ):

```
library(tidyverse)    
survey <- survey %>%
    mutate(birth_country = if_else(
                str_detect(birth_country, 
                           "(united state)|(united statea)|(united states of america)"), #If your regular expression matches any in birth_country
                "america", #Change it to "america"
                birth_country #Otherwise, keep as is.
                ) #end of if_else
           ) #end of mutate
```

Other people are suggesting you come up with a more complex regular expression, which you can certainly do as well. Consecutive "or" (i.e. "|") statements in your regular expression works though.

Comment: brilliant! Thanks so much! This worked great, except i realised that it replaces every thing with america. So some people have written US and others US of A, and I need these replaced with 'america', if I do what I originally wanted to do, and correct my regular expression as you so helpfully pointed out, I just end up with 'america of A'
as US was replaced. Perhaps this needs a more complicated reg expression :(

Comment: Oh I see @Gabriella, I've updated my answer to what you're looking for.

Comment: wow that worked PERFECTLY! And thanks for explaining so clearly at each line. I am so so grateful

Answer (score 2):

Come up with some patterns that only match for each country and basically loop over what you are already doing (you can change the replacement below with your favorite function)

```
survey <- structure(list(birth_country = c("america", "usa", "american", "us of a", "united states", "england", "english", "great britain",  "uk", "united kingdom")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

## use a _named_ list of regular expressions
## the name will be the replacement string
l <- list(
  america = 'amer|us|states',
  uk = 'eng|brit|king|uk',
  'another country' = 'ano|an co',
  chaz = 'chaz|chop'
)

f <- function(x, list) {
  for (ii in seq_along(list)) {
    x[grepl(list[[ii]], x, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- names(list)[ii]
  }
  x
}

## test it
f(survey$birth_country, l)
# [1] "america" "america" "america" "america" "america" "uk"      "uk"      "uk"      "uk"      "uk"     

within(survey, {
  clean <- f(birth_country, l)
})
#     birth_country   clean
# 1         america america
# 2             usa america
# 3        american america
# 4         us of a america
# 5   united states america
# 6         england      uk
# 7         english      uk
# 8   great britain      uk
# 9              uk      uk
# 10 united kingdom      uk
```

Note that 1) if you don't give a pattern that matches, nothing will change, but 2) if you give a pattern that matches both countries (e.g., "united"), the first in the list will be used (unless the replacement itself is also matched)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. 
I'm pretty new to R so I have some follow up questions which are pretty basic, if you don't mind (feel free to ignore-I'm sure you're busy!) In your answer,i don't understand the first line,
`survey <- structure`...

If I'm correct, you've renamed survey, and are then creating a list of vectors "america", "usa", "american", "us of a and so on. 
my first Q is why create the list of vectors? As these are already a column in my data, and why those particular row names? 
thanks :)

Comment: that line is just to put the example data you have in your question into a usable format. it's good practice to have a re-producible example in your question (if nothing else to avoid an onslaught of comments). you can use `dput(survey)` to get this format which can just be copy/pasted into your question

Answer (score 1):

In case you allow tidyverse`s mutate you can do:

```r
library(tidyverse)
survey <- structure(list(birth_country = c("america", "usa", "american", "us of a", "united states", "england", "english", "great britain",  "uk", "united kingdom")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

americas <- c("america", "usa", "american", "us of a", "united states")
englands <- c("england", "english", "great britain")
survey %>% 
  mutate(birth_country = ifelse(birth_country %in% americas, 'america', 'UK'))
#>    birth_country
#> 1        america
#> 2        america
#> 3        america
#> 4        america
#> 5        america
#> 6             UK
#> 7             UK
#> 8             UK
#> 9             UK
#> 10            UK
```